# Error in zend_db_select statement to return as new column

Tags: zend-db, zend-db-select

I am trying the return with a new column named count. Here is my query. $userid is the paramter to pass in

```
        $select = $this->db->select()
            ->from('myfriend')
            ->where('fromid=?', $userid)
            ->join('user', 'user.userid = friends.toid')
            ->columns( new Zend_Db_Expr('Select count(*) where friends.toid = $userid as count'))
            ->order("id desc")
            ->limit(20);
```

I want to return a new column called count. where it will display number of rows where friends.toid = userid.

Seems to have some syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use double quotes, not single quotes, so php can eval `$userid`, like `"Select count(*) where friends.toid = $userid as count"`

If you want to debug your query, you can always use:

```
echo $select->__toString()
```